# WPF/Silverlight: How to add a command to a modified control template?

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, xaml

I have overridden a control template for a certain 3rd party control that I am using:

So

```
<Style TargetType="Some3rdPartyControl">
   <Setter Property="Template">
     <Setter.Value>
       <ControlTemplate TargetType="Some3rdPartyControl">
       <Grid>
         ...alot of stuff..
      </Grid>
      </ControlTemplate>
     </Setter.Value>
   </Setter>
</Style>
```

Basically, I have added a button inside the control template:

```
<Style TargetType="Some3rdPartyControl">
<Setter Property="Template">
<Setter.Value>
   <ControlTemplate TargetType="Some3rdPartyControl">
   <Grid>
     <Button x:Name="myButton" Width="20" Height="20">
     ...alot of stuff..
   </Grid>
   </ControlTemplate>
   </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
</Style>
```

Basically, I'd like to hook up an event, err probably a command to this new button... How do I do this? Which type of command is it, and where would it live? I don't have access to the actual .cs class of this third party control.So I'm hoping this command could live somewhere in a file that I generate, is this even possible?

Answer (score 0):

This Command comes from the templated parent i.e. `Some3rdPartyControl` ...

Does your `Some3rdPartyControl` has a `Command` type depepdency property in it? If yes then you can do a `TemplateBinding` to that.

```
       <Button x:Name="myButton" Command="{TemplateBinding Command}" Width="20" Height="20">
```

Else you will have to create a Command type attached property to your `Some3rdPartyControl` and use that to `TemplateBinding` to the Button.

```
    <Style TargetType="Some3rdPartyControl">
       <Setter Property="Template">
           <Setter.Value>
             <ControlTemplate TargetType="Some3rdPartyControl">
               <Grid>
                 <Button x:Name="myButton" Width="20" Height="20" Command="{TemplateBinding myNamespace:MyAttachedBehavior.MyAttachedCommand}">
                    ...alot of stuff..
               </Grid>
             </ControlTemplate>
           </Setter.Value>
       </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Now while implementing your `Some3rdPartyControl` do this...

```
   <Some3rdPartyControl myNamespace:MyAttachedBehavior.MyAttachedCommand="{Binding CommandFromDataContextViewModel}" />
```

CommandFromDataContextViewModel is your custom command. Due to TemplateBinding it reaches the Button and when Button click happnes this CommandFromDataContextViewModel command executes.

Does this answer your question?

Comment: I didn't quite understand your first example Command="{TemplateBinding Command}" ... I want to launch my own custom command how would this accomplish that?

Comment: I have edited my answer... use the second option instead ... Now it explains how your custmom command can be specified against the Button using TemplateBinding ...

Answer (score 0):

You can have  your command in your ViewModel and can bind that command to the button by simply using the RealtiveSource for binding like this -

```
 <Style TargetType="Some3rdPartyControl">
    <Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
       <ControlTemplate TargetType="Some3rdPartyControl">
       <Grid>
         <Button x:Name="myButton" Width="20" Height="20"
 Command="{Binding DataContext.YourCommandName, RelativeSource={RealtiveSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}">
         ...alot of stuff..
       </Grid>
       </ControlTemplate>
       </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want a Command Property for your UserControl, or a static Command Definition?

If you want a Command Property, such as the `Button.Command` property, you need to create your own command definition in the code behind your UserControl. Look up creating your own custom `DependencyProperty` for that. The command that gets executed would "live" in whatever your DataContext was and the XAML code would look something like this:

```
<local:MyCustomControl SomeCustomCommand="{Binding SomeCommand}" />
```

If it's going to be a static Command Definition, like `Copy` or `Paste` commands, you need to create the static `ICommand` somewhere that the XAML can access, and bind the XAML with something like this:

```
<Button Command="{x:Static local:SomeCustomCommand}" />
```